# error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts' failed: 404 Not Found

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, io, deno

I get the following error message but I don't know which part of the program causes this error message because I can not find a direct importing of these libraries in my app:

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-write --unstable server.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts
Download https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/bufio.ts
Warning std versions prefixed with 'v' were deprecated recently. Please change your import to https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/io/util.ts 
(at https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts)
Warning std versions prefixed with 'v' were deprecated recently. Please change your import to https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/io/bufio.ts (at https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/bufio.ts)
error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@v0.51.0/io/util.ts' failed: 404 Not Found
    at https://deno.land/x/dejs@0.7.0/vendor/https/deno.land/std/io/util.ts:1:0
```

What is the problem? How can I find and resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Deno's [dependency inspector](https://deno.land/manual@v1.14.3/tools/dependency_inspector), you can see a hierarchical relationship of all dependencies included in your entrypoint module. Use like this:

```
deno info [OPTIONS] [URL or FILE_PATH]
```

---

Here's an example to illustrate:

In the terminal:

```
% ls
deps.ts     mod.ts      test.ts     test_deps.ts

% deno info test.ts
local: /Users/deno/example/test.ts
type: TypeScript
emit: /Users/deno/.deno/gen/file/Users/deno/example/test.ts.js
dependencies: 17 unique (total 107.24KB)

file:///Users/deno/example/test.ts (284B)
├─┬ file:///Users/deno/example/mod.ts (308B)
│ └─┬ file:///Users/deno/example/deps.ts (67B)
│   └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/mod.ts (725B)
│     ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/_util/os.ts (598B)
│     ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_interface.ts (728B)
│     ├─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/common.ts (1.16KB)
│     │ └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/separator.ts (259B)
│     │   └── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/_util/os.ts *
│     ├─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/glob.ts (12.36KB)
│     │ ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/_util/os.ts *
│     │ ├─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/posix.ts (14.49KB)
│     │ │ ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_constants.ts (1.9KB)
│     │ │ ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_interface.ts *
│     │ │ └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_util.ts (3.62KB)
│     │ │   ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_constants.ts *
│     │ │   └── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_interface.ts *
│     │ ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/separator.ts *
│     │ └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/win32.ts (29.41KB)
│     │   ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/_util/assert.ts (405B)
│     │   ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_constants.ts *
│     │   ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_interface.ts *
│     │   └── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/_util.ts *
│     ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/posix.ts *
│     ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/separator.ts *
│     └── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/win32.ts *
└─┬ file:///Users/deno/example/test_deps.ts (66B)
  └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/testing/asserts.ts (20.63KB)
    ├── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/fmt/colors.ts (11.53KB)
    └── https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/testing/_diff.ts (8.78KB)
```

The text contents of the modules in the contrived example:

`deps.ts`:

```ts
export * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/path/mod.ts";
```

`mod.ts`:

```ts
import { path } from "./deps.ts";

const imageExtensions = new Set([
  "apng",
  "avci",
  "avif",
  "gif",
  "heic",
  "heif",
  "jpeg",
  "jpg",
  "png",
  "svg",
  "webp",
]);

export function hasImageExtension(filePath: string): boolean {
  return imageExtensions.has(path.extname(filePath).slice(1));
}
```

`test_deps.ts`:

```ts
export * from "https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/testing/asserts.ts";
```

`test.ts`:

```ts
import { assert } from "./test_deps.ts";
import { hasImageExtension } from "./mod.ts";

Deno.test("hasImageExtension", () => {
  let filePath = "./images/logo.png";
  assert(hasImageExtension(filePath));
  filePath = "./images/README.txt";
  assert(!hasImageExtension(filePath));
});
```